# How to modify the type declaration so we don't have to change Either to be a type constructor?

Tags: haskell

```
{- data Either e a = Left e | Right a
   from the standard library.

   It's like Maybe, but the "no answer" case carries extra data, perhaps some kind
   of reason for why "no answer".
-}
fmap_Either :: (a -> b) -> (Either e) a -> (Either e) b
fmap_Either f (Left e) = Left e
fmap_Either f (Right a) = Right (f a)
```

This is an example in my lecture. Since the function takes only one parameter `a` and the output will become type `b`. We have to change `Either e a` to be a type constructor `(Either e) a`. I am wondering can we modify the function, which will take 2 parameters so that we can write `Either e a` instead of `(Either e) a`. Though I'm not sure if it is a good idea.

Comment: Those two types are the same, though spelling it as `(Either e) a` makes it easier to match up against type classes like `Functor`.

Comment: In Haskell all functions take *exactly* one parameter. This also applies for type constructors.

Comment: Ahhh, that's true. But can we use a curried form?

Comment: @user8314628: yes, in fact if `Either` is already a `Functor` instance, and if we look up the source code, we see `instance Functor (Either e) where ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> can we modify the function, which will take 2 parameters so that we can write `Either e a` instead of `(Either e) a`. Though I'm not sure if it is a good idea.

This is already the case, in Haskell `Either e a` is the *same* as `(Either e) a`. The former simply removes some "noise", but behind the curtains if you write `Either e a`, you have actually written `(Either e) a`.

In Haskell every function takes exactly one parameter. This also holds for type constructors: a type constructor takes one type parameter. If we thus write types that require two or more type parameters, we actually have written a type constructor that takes one type and produces a new "type constructor" that will take other parameters.

This concept is actually used frequently in typeclasses. Take for example the [**`Functor` typeclass**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#Functor) (the typeclass that defines the `fmap` function):

> ```
> class  Functor f where
>     fmap        :: (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
>     (<$)        :: a -> f b -> f a
>     (<$)        =  fmap . const
> ```

We here see that `f` is a type constructor that takes a type parameter, since in the body of the typeclass, we make types `f a` and `f b`.

If we then look to the [**`Functor` instance of `Either`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/src/Data.Either.html#line-129) we see:

> ```
> instance Functor (Either e) where
>     fmap _ (Left x) = Left x
>     fmap f (Right y) = Right (f y)
> ```

(I replaced `(Either a)` with `(Either e)` since the `a` in the `instance` declaration is a different `a` than the one in the `class` definition, so to avoid confusion)

So here `f` is `Either e`, and thus `f a` will be an `(Either e) a` or `Either e a`.